# How to get an XML document validated using .NET XmlDocument class and namespaces

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 application which formats some data using the `XmlDocument` class and related classes.  We have a customer requirement to apply some attributes to the root node of the document, these attributes are government defined, specifics are below.  I call  `XmlDocument.Validate()` to assure the correctness of my document; I am getting errors about the attributes on the root element, specifics below.

I have two XSD files which I use, the first is XXXXSchema.xsd and this defines the element names for my document.  The second is IC-ISM.xsd, this is a shortened version of a document which can be obtained from http://www.dni.gov/files/documents/CIO/ICEA/ISMPublic.zip.  I have included only the definitions of the attributes which I need to use in my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This is a minimal version of IC-ISM.xsd -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:us:gov:ic:ism"
    xmlns:ism="urn:us:gov:ic:ism" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    targetNamespace="urn:us:gov:ic:ism" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified" >

    <xsd:attribute name="classification">
    </xsd:attribute>

    <xsd:attribute name="resourceElement">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:schema>
```

Here is my C# .NET code:

```
private XmlElement CreateElement(string elementName, IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodeSubList) {
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    const string rootElementName = "XXXX_DATA";
    const string ICMSchemaURI = "urn:us:gov:ic:ism";

    xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(null, @"XXXXSchema.xsd");
    xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(ICMSchemaURI, @"IC-ISM.xsd");

    XmlElement rootElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement(rootElementName);

    XmlAttribute nsAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xmlns", "ism", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
    nsAttr.Value = ICMSchemaURI;
    rootElement.Attributes.Append(nsAttr);

    rootElement.SetAttribute("resourceElement", ICMSchemaURI, "true");
    rootElement.SetAttribute("classification", ICMSchemaURI, "U");

    // Insert the root element into the new, empty document
    xmlDoc.InsertAfter(rootElement, null);

    // Create an element with the specified name, within the root
    XmlElement namedElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement(elementName);
    rootElement.InsertAfter(namedElement, null);

    [... code here to insert elements within the document...]

    xmlDoc.Validate(ValidationEventHandler);
    return xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
}
```

If I capture the XML of my document in the debugger, the top level element looks like this:

```
XXXX_DATA xmlns:ism="urn:us:gov:ic:ism" 
    ism:resourceElement="true" 
    ism:classification="U"
```

But the validation method generates these error messages:

"**The 'urn:us:gov:ic:ism:resourceElement' attribute is not declared.**"

"**The 'urn:us:gov:ic:ism:classification' attribute is not declared.**"

I have read all the documentation I can find on the use of XML schemas and namespaces, I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: After the two adds, try `xmlDoc.Schemas.Compile()`. Also, I recommend you examine the resulting `xmlDoc.Schemas` to see if, for instance, the two attributes show up in the [`GlobalAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.globalattributes.aspx) property.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is that the ISM schema does not declare your element. The ISM schema is something that should be used by another schema it does not do much on it's own. You may want to contact the folks who maintain it at ic-standards-support@intelink.gov

Comment: -1: no, it's not necessary for a schema to declare the element. Declaring the attributes should be sufficient.